# For as long as there has been a CIA there have been rumors of men in black

Tags: meaning-in-context

Does "a CIA" in this passage refer to individual CIA agents or the CIA as an institution?

> For as long as there has been **a CIA** there have been rumors of men in
> black. Nameless spies who descend from black helicopters and kidnap
> those who know too much. These mysterious men gangstalk unwitting
> victims and perform psychological operations on the public. Known to
> schizo-posters as “glowies”, a term taken from one of their heroes
> Terry Davis, these feds lurk about every corner of the internet,
> laying traps and deploying psyops on hapless posters. This paranoia is
> only exacerbated by the increased interest in intelligence agencies,
> and especially by the Biden administration’s new counter-terror
> initiatives. Designating and tracking so-called “extremists” will be a
> major priority as national security increasingly focuses on domestic
> terror in the foreseeable future.
>
> https://legacy.donotresearch.net/posts/millenarian-dreams-of-the-schizo-scene

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means “for as long as the CIA has existed,” or, expressed a bit more quirkily but more nearly parallel to the original, “for as long as there has been an organization identical to the CIA.”

So of the two alternatives you offer, it’s the agency itself.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. But what is the point of conveying a complicated meaning like "an organization identical to the CIA," when you just say "the CIA" and everyone understands it?

Comment: One wouldn’t. And that’s why the speaker (or author) didn’t.

Comment: Sorry but what do you mean by "the speaker (or author) didn’t"? The author did use "a CIA," which has a more complicated meaning than "the CIA," didn't he?

Comment: No, “**a** CIA” is neither more nor less complicated in meaning than is “**the** CIA.” It **is** far less common but sounds perfectly acceptable (if off-beat) to native speakers.  How about a third paraphrase: “for as long as there has been such a thing as the CIA”? That may help you see why the speaker used the indefinite article, even though *CIA* is a name and has a single, unique referent; it’s “such **a** thing.” In any event, the expression *there is* generally doesn’t get on as well with complements with definite articles: “\*for as long as there has been **the** CIA” isn’t idiomatic.

Comment: Ah, I fully understand now. Thank you so much.